# Facebook IOS in-app login dialog not hiding password

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm adding the Facebook Connect library in my iPhone app and everything is working great except for one nagging issue. The problem happens in the in-app Facebook login dialog. When I type password into the text field, the dialog correctly obscures it with •••••••. However, if I happen to mistype the password, the dialog reloads and on the second try shows the password without the ••••. Is there a way to fix this? I have the FBDialog.bundle in my project.

Comment: The sdk actually show the oauth webpage in dialog from facebook. So you cannot make any change to the sdk as it is the nature of facebook oauth page for mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Facebook's mobile login works in both the SDK and regular mobile site - there's a message to this effect when the dialog is displayed the second time

Comment: So there's no way to turn that off?